# Curl SSL Connect error

Tags: php, curl

I integrating Paypal adaptive payment for my site.Itz works perfect in local.but when I tried it in live server it shows me an error.I came to know that the error is due to the curl SSL Connect error.
Can anyone help me with this?

```
 $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiUrl.$call);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);

    return json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);

    print_r( json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE) );   

    echo '<pre>';print_r( curl_getinfo($ch) ); echo '</pre>'; echo '<br>';
```

Comment: What is the error shown?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make ssl verifier false like below. It might help you.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

EDIT

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
```

Comment: Try to provide client ID as well. I have edited answer for this.

Comment: I dont have a clientId,I have only API User,API Id,API pass,API sig